# Laravel 5.6.12 how to redirect to plain html angular 4 app after login

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel, redirect, single-page-application

I want to use my laravel installation as a session and request handler without using blade view templates. I've added an auth controller to the app with:

```
php artisan make:auth
```

And login, register, forgot password etc. all work perfectly. What I wanna do though is to redirect the user to an angular 4 single page app that resides in a subfolder named dashboard-dist in laravel root which I build independently from the laravel project. In other words I don't want to use the V in MVC of laravel and have angular handle the views.

I want to use restful API calls to laravel controllers to do the rest of back-end business apart from login, register etc.. How can I redirect the user to index.html inside this folder and keep the session goodness at the same time and have restful request handlers work?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: What I didn't try is to convert the angular project into a blade template which seems cumbersome to me.

Comment: Can't you place it inside views folder regardless it's not blade? Because if you do that then its easy to redirect it there

Comment: I don't want to contaminate the view structure of laravel. I want the angular project to stay in its independent folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I edited the config/view.php:

```
'paths' => [
    resource_path('views'),
    public_path('dashboard-dist'),
],
```

And then built the angular project to reflect that base href change:

```
ng build --base-href /dashboard-dist/
```

And voila... Angular 4 inside the laravel goodness.

Answer (score 0):

1) Compile your angular app

2) Change your angular index.html entry point to be index.blade.php and move it to the views folder, then fix all js and css files connections

3) Create a route to render that view

4) Use `return redirect(route)` to redirect to that route from wherever you need

5) ...

6) PROFIT!!!11

Comment: There's dozen of other options really, ping me if this one won't work

Comment: This is the option I wanted to avoid all along. How about putting the angular dist into public folder and somehow redirect to the html keeping the session going if it's possible?

Comment: Not sure if putting a compiled js into public a good idea. It will cause troubles later on upon creating edits inside angular.
Consider also including index.html of your ng app into any laravel view by using the following workaround https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_include.asp